# display multiple mysql rows in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table called jobcardlabour. It has 3 colums, Jobcard, Description, Quantity and Amount. When I create a jobcard I enter the work I have done into this table. I know want to create an invoice so I want to call this table and display the results in a html table on the printable invoice. I can do this but where I am having difficulty is there might be 3 or more rows which all have the same jobcard number. I need all the rows displayed in the table. The table needs three headings, called Description, Qty and Amount. If anyone can help with the basics I can modify it to suit my needs. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the information, then just do

```
SELECT * FROM jobcardlabour;
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to get all the information, what I dont know is how to display ALL the rows that have the same jobcard number in a table. Thats what I am stuck on.